# Razón por la que si cambio common.d.ts, ionic serve no falla

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic-framework, dependencias

Tengo una duda y espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Cuando ejecuto ionic serve tengo el siguiente error:

> [app-scripts] [15:04:28] transpile started ... [app-scripts]
>   [15:04:42] typescript:
>   ...aceIcaro_5_3B/dev-app/app/node_modules/@ionic-native/core/decorators/common.d.ts,
>   line: 10 [app-scripts] Cannot find name 'unknown'. [app-scripts] L9:
>   export declare function wrapPromise(pluginObj: any, methodName:
>   string, args: any[], opts?: CordovaOptions): Promise; [app-scripts]
>   L11: * Checks if plugin/cordova is available

He leído que si se cambia unknown por any en la línea 10 de common.d.ts en @ionic-native/core/decorators, el error desaparece. Es cierto pero quiero saber la razón.

Mis dependencias en package.json son:

> "dependencies": { "@angular/animations": "^5.2.11", "@angular/common":
>   "^5.2.11", "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11", "@angular/compiler-cli":
>   "^5.2.11", "@angular/core": "^5.2.11", "@angular/forms": "^5.2.11",
>   "@angular/http": "^5.2.11", "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.11",
>   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.11", "@angular/router":
>   "^5.2.11", "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.2.0",
>   "@ionic-native/app-version": "5.14.0", "@ionic-native/core": "5.14.0",
>   "@ionic-native/date-picker": "5.14.0", "@ionic-native/file":
>   "^5.14.0", "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.14.0",
>   "@ionic-native/globalization": "5.14.0",
>   "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.14.0",
>   "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "5.14.0",
>   "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.14.0", "@ionic-native/status-bar":
>   "5.14.0", "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0", "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
>   "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1", "@types/lodash": "4.14.118",
>   "cordova": "^9.0.0", "cordova-android": "8.1.0", "cordova-browser":
>   "6.0.0", "cordova-ios": "5.0.1", "cordova-plugin-app-version":
>   "^0.1.9", "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
>   "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3", "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
>   "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
>   "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
>   "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.1.0",
>   "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
>   "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
>   "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3", "cordova-plugin-statusbar":
>   "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
>   "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4", "ionic-angular": "^3.9.8",
>   "ionic-tooltips": "^2.1.1", "ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.3.1", "ionicons":
>   "^3.0.0", "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0", "lodash": "4.17.11", "moment":
>   "^2.24.0", "ngx-permissions": "^4.1.0", "node-sass": "^4.11.0", "run":
>   "1.4.0", "rxjs": "^5.5.12", "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0", "zone.js": "0.8.26"
>   }, "devDependencies": { "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.2", "@ionic/lab":
>   "1.0.6", "typescript": "2.8.3" }

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución. Hice estos cambios porque en un dispositivo con iOS13 no podía visualizar el calendario y el reloj nativos.

Así que se puede decir que tengo dos soluciones.

El problema con el calenaddrio y el reloj es debido al nuevo modo oscuro, así que he forzado que el modo claro cuando se abre mi app con iOs.

El problema con dependencias es más complicado. He vuelto a una versión anterior y todo ha funcionado bien. Si quisiera actualizar mis dependencias, debería reemplazar “ionic-angular” por “@ionic/angular”, actualizar typescript, todo @angular/* stuff se debería unir a @angular/core y “ionic2-super-tabs” podría generar problemas. Por lo que es mejor generar un nuevo proyecto y migrar mi código.